# Cutting Grass in Die2Nite

Tags: die2nite

When I am playing die2nite, I really dont care how long the grass is. With that said, I found a lawnmower. What should I do with it instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lawnmower is a weapon that if found incomplete requires Duct Tape, Nuts & Bolts and Wrought Iron to build.

The lawnmower kills 2 zombies per use, with a 30% chance of breaking.  It can be repaired using the Repair Kit or Kwik-Fix; however, this action takes 1 AP.  Due to the 1 AP cost to repair while out in the field, it becomes less useful once your town has built Plumbing, especially because on average, you should get around 6-8 kills per repair.  So with 2-3 repair kits it may well kill more zombies than a cart full of pistols, but the AP cost and the number of zombies it will destroy is not guaranteed so it is unreliable.

Answer (score 5):

Lawnmowers are actually weapons that can be used against zombies (nice mental image there, eh?). They'll take out two zombies from a zone that you're in, with a chance of the weapon breaking, of course.

If you happened to find it in the incomplete state, it requires duct tape, nuts & bolts and wrought iron to build.

Comment: Correct.  Each hit kills 2 zombies.  According to the French wiki, it has a 30% chance of breaking with each strike, which would then require repairing it with a Kwik-Fix or Repair kit.  Not so great considering it requires nuts & bolts to build.

Comment: we usually do 7 attacks with it, thus killing 14zs with each repair kit. it is our best weapon to take out and clear paths since we got 1 repair kit which we repair for 1 ap at workshop :). we consider it great :)

Comment: [Here is an example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7z8m6xs3rKA)  of how it can be used.  **Warning: EXTREME blood and gore.**